# Prompt default value in Microstrategy Mobile

Tags: microstrategy

I have a simple mobile document in Microstrategy Mobile, running on IPhone, containing a table of values and a drop-down selector that filters those values.

Is there any way to set the default value of the drop-down selector? If yes, is there any way I can set it dynamically(say based on some user-related attribute)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most common question asked . This issue has been fixed in v9.4 .You can decide what should be the initial value .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A selector isn't the same as a prompt. If it was a prompt, you could set the default value in the prompt definition when editing or creating the prompt.

If you want a default value for a selector, it's slightly different. Execute the document in Web, and set the selector value you want. Then just save the document. The next time it's executed in Web or Mobile, it should just have the saved value.